# How to batch modify classes modifier in a .Net Assembly from internal to public?

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, decompiling

I have a third-party .Net assembly dll and I want to know if there is a tool that I can use to quickly update all `internal class` to `public class`. I can use dnSpy to modify them one by one, but it's not very efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just write a small tool for that.

Use [Mono.Cecil](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/) and iterate through all the types in a `Module` and change the `IsPublic` to `true`. After that just call Write.

Something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (AssemblyDefinition a = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(args[0], new ReaderParameters { ReadWrite = true }))
    {
        foreach (var type in a.Modules[0].Types)
        {
            if (type.IsNotPublic)
                type.IsPublic = true;
        }
        a.Write();
    }
}
```